# WCF and HTTP GET

Tags: wcf, http

My WCF service exposes this function

```
public SerialNumberInfo GetSerialNumberInfo(string serialNumber) { }
```

Is there a way to enable HTTP GET on my WCF service? Example:

```
http://localhost:8004/MyService/GetSerialNumberInfo?serialNumber=4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, you need to use the `webHttpBinding` on your WCF service.

See the WCF REST Starter Kit for more information on REST Support in WCF.

- [REST in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529.aspx)
- [Overview of REST in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd547388.aspx)
- [Series of screencasts on how to use REST in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd547387.aspx)

If you're hosting your service in IIS, you need to create a separate *.svc file for the REST service (let's call it `RESTService.svc`), which contains:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="YourServiceName" Language="C#" debug="False"
    Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>
```

Now you should be able to connect to the URL

```
http://localhost:8004/MyService/RESTService.svc
```

and get your data RESTfully.

Marc

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do sounds like building a RESTful service with WCF. Check out the following article on MSDN, it has all the details:

> [**A Guide to Designing and Building RESTful Web Services with WCF 3.5**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx)