# Which Visual Studio project type for a C# server process

Tags: c#, web

I need to do something fairly simple. I have a Windows Server on which I need to have a process, receiving HTTP requests (with parameters in GET mode).
These parameters are to be parsed, to then send back some XML to the user.

I've done such things fairly easily in Python, where I could basically map a procedure (its name was the suffix or the url, and parameters the arguments of a GET or POST method indifferently).

What's the best way to achieve this in C# ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds to me like you want to setup an http reqest [handler](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4643/implementing-http-handlers-in-aspnet/).  If you however need to not use IIS you can setup an wcf get server [WCF and HTTP GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380075/wcf-and-http-get)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to create a Web Application or MVC application and deploy it on IIS.

If you go for an MVC project than you can define your routes, essentially maps between urls and your procedures.

With WebForms Web Applications you can also use routes, or you create pages with certain names.

In both cases you can create custom HttpHandlers, but it's a bit pointless in case of MVC (an action is good enough).

Comment: But then, how to map a url to a procedure ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this on a Website project.  After you do your processing you can easily return the raw XML by using Response.Write() and setting the appropriate ContentType.

Instead of using an aspx page, you could implement this using an HTTPHandler, have a [look at this](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/asp/writing-a-custom-http-handler-in-asp-net) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify on some of the other answers here - you can use either an application made to be hosted in IIS (eg Web Application, MVC web application etc) or if you do not want to use IIS you could create a windows service to host a WCF service.